# SignalR- Removing a Client From signalR Hub

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to remove a client from **signalR** hub using its **connectionId**? I'am trying to create an application in which I can remove a client from hub?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR does not provide an API to disconnect clients. You could workaround it by defining a client method and in the body call connection.stop()

Answer (score 1):

SignalR version 2 does not have a built-in server API for disconnecting clients. In the current SignalR release, the simplest way to disconnect a client from the server is to implement a disconnect method on the client and call that method from the server. The following code sample shows a disconnect method for a JavaScript client using the generated proxy.

`var myHubProxy = $.connection.myHub
myHubProxy.client.stopClient = function() {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
};`

> Security Note: Neither this method for disconnecting clients nor the proposed built-in API will address the scenario of hacked clients that are running malicious code, since the clients could reconnect or the hacked code might remove the stopClient method or change what it does. The appropriate place to implement stateful denial-of-service (DOS) protection is not in the framework or the server layer, but rather in front-end infrastructure.

[More details here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)